# Qiskit qubit ordering

Tags: qiskit, qaoa

In their `to_ising` [documantation page](https://qiskit.org/ecosystem/optimization/stubs/qiskit_optimization.translators.to_ising.html), Qiskit devs mark the comment:

> Variables are mapped to qubits in the same order, i.e., $i$-th variable is mapped to $i$-th qubit.

I'm aware that Qiskit follows little endian, the rightmost bit being the least significant, but still a bit confused about the statement.

Suppose an example Ising Hamiltonian generated with `to_ising`:

```
...
+ 0.12072225349199095 * IIIIIZ
...
```

If I want to build a circuit with it, on which qubit should I apply the $Z$-gate? My initial guess was `q[5]`(the bottommost qubit in the circuit), since the comment states that they're in the same order, but automatically building the circuit with the Hamiltonian and `QAOAAnsatz` shows it mirrored, i.e. $Z$ applied to `q[0]`(the uppermost in the circuit).

Is that corresponding to what's intended, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using little-endian ordering implies that if $A$ and $B$ are two operators, then $B \otimes A$ means: apply $A$ to first qubit and $B$ to second qubit.

So, while in most quantum computing textbooks the bitstring $011$ means that the first bit equals zero, in Qiskit it will mean that the last bit equals zero. Similary, the Pauli string $XYZ$ will be written in Qiskit as $ZYX$.

Hence, in your case you should apply $Z$ operator to the first qubit (i.e., `q[0]`)

You can find more information [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/explanation/endianness.html).

Comment: So q[0] is indeed the 6th (last) qubit, as far as I understand? In the example above the Z operator is the 6th variable, so it should be mapped to the 6th qubit, according to the doc page.

Comment: No! I updated my answer. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Ok. So Z in the example should be referred to as the first variable, which is then applied to the first qubit, q[0]. Makes more sense now. Thank you!

Comment: Yes! That's correct.